# Why my "<asp:ListView" isn't showing on the screen?

Tags: asp.net, listview

This is part of my code that isn't working. I have looked for somethings, but i cannot search what my `asp:ListView` isn't showing, if someone knows about it, Help me !

```
<asp:ListView  ItemPlaceholderID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" ID="ListViewUser">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"/>
        <table id="Table1" class="TableListView" runat="server">
            <tr id="Tr1" class="TableHeader" runat="server">
                <td id="td1" runat="server">Nível</td>
                <td id="td2" runat="server">Descrição</td>
                <td id="td3" runat="server">Quantidade de Problema ?</td>
                <td id="td4" runat="server">Selecionar</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="ItemsCSS">
            <td>
               <asp:Label runat="server"
                    ID="Label1"                                      
                    Text="Problema" >  
               </asp:Label>  
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server"
                    ID="Label2"                                      
                    Text="Problema" >  
               </asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server"
                    ID="Label3"                                      
                    Text="Problema" >  
               </asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not working"? Is there an error? Please provide more detail so other people can help better.

Comment: How are you populating the `DataSource`?

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to show this ListView on the screen here in my project of work and I'm getting confused, because there isn't showing any error on the screen, but this lisView isn't showing here. So, for this reason I'm getting consufed, cause if it isn't showing any error, How can't it showing ? When I'm going to the Split in asp.net project, it shows but it looks like a mess in the middle of project, but when I will debug, it doesn't show !

Comment: If you don't bind the `ListView` to some data, it has nothing to show. It won't appear on the page, because it has nothing to show. It won't show an error, because it's not an error. Either set the `DataSourceID` to the ID of a data source control, or set the `DataSource` to a list of data and call the `DataBind()` method from the code-behind.

Comment: Oh cool. Thank you richard, now I got it why it isn't showing, I wasn't bind the ListView to a data, just putting the text. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ListView` lacks bindings. You can add a `DataSourceID` property to the top level control  and point to a `DataSource` control or programmatically bind to the `DataSource` property and then invoke `DataBind()`. But the control will not display anything without first binding it.

Comment: thanks. I'm going to copy exactly the same thing that I wrote to other guy. I will try what you said, but if you can understand better, read this: 
Okay, I'm trying to show this ListView on the screen here in my project of work and I'm getting confused, because there isn't showing any error on the screen, but this lisView isn't showing here. So, for this reason I'm getting consufed, cause if it isn't showing any error, How can't it showing ? When I'm going to the Split in asp.net project, it shows but it looks like a mess in the middle of project, but when I will debug, it doesn't show !